# Longtable and threeparttablex: wrong position of tablenote when table is textwidth

Tags: longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

I have a problem with `longtable` and the position of a table note created by `threeparttablex`, as the MWE below demonstrates. The first table stretches to the full textwidth and the position of the table note is incorrect. The second table does not specify any table size and the table note is correct. Am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,threeparttablex,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
 \begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]This is a wrong tablenote\end{TableNotes}
 \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
 \setlength\LTright{0pt}
 \begin{longtable}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{3}{c}}
  \caption{Longtable with Full Textwidth}\\
  \toprule
   Variable 1 & 1.85   & 0.92   & 1.11   \\
              & (0.34) & (0.24) & (0.14) \\
  \bottomrule
  \insertTableNotes
 \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
 \begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]This is a good tablenote\end{TableNotes}
 \begin{longtable}[c]{l*{3}{c}}
  \caption{Normal Longtable}\\
  \toprule
   Variable 1 & 1.85   & 0.92   & 1.11   \\
              & (0.34) & (0.24) & (0.14) \\
  \bottomrule
  \insertTableNotes
 \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the table notes width is computed taking into account only the natural width of the table without the `\fill` component.

Comment: @egreg Mh, yes. I wanted to double check that I did not miss something completely obvious, the correct width (to me) is the main function of threeparttables. Do you think that can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure. But my idea about tables is that trying to spread them to the line width is wrong.

Comment: @egreg I agree to some extent, but it appears to be common in many (most?) Economics journals.

Comment: Thus they can make difficult for the readers to follow the data in one row. It may be a good technique. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Damn, you have discovered our secret...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `threeparttablex` is only able to measure the natural width of the table, so the “`\fill`” components are not taken into account. But since you *know* the width, in that case, you can redefine `\TPTminimum` for the duration of the environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,threeparttablex,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
 \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
 \setlength\LTright{0pt}
 \renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth} %%% we want full width
 \begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]
  This is a wrong tablenote
  This is a wrong tablenote
  This is a wrong tablenote
  This is a wrong tablenote
  This is a wrong tablenote
\end{TableNotes}
 \begin{longtable}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{3}{c}}
  \caption{Longtable with Full Textwidth}\\
  \toprule
   Variable 1 & 1.85   & 0.92   & 1.11   \\
              & (0.34) & (0.24) & (0.14) \\
  \bottomrule
  \insertTableNotes
 \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
 \begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]This is a good tablenote\end{TableNotes}
 \begin{longtable}[c]{l*{3}{c}}
  \caption{Normal Longtable}\\
  \toprule
   Variable 1 & 1.85   & 0.92   & 1.11   \\
              & (0.34) & (0.24) & (0.14) \\
  \bottomrule
  \insertTableNotes
 \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll let the package maintainer know of this, maybe he's interested in incorporating it.

Comment: Actually it might more be a `longtable` problem? How does one get `longtable` to report the true width? The width I get back are the same in both cases. I use the data stored in the `.aux` file to calculate the width. But that does not take the `\fill` into account.